# mget `*.*` doesn't work

Tags: command-line, ftp, filename, wildcards

I want to download all files in a folder with ftp. But mget `*.*` isn't accepted. Here is the terminal output:

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Directory listing for /DCIM/Camera/
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 0 Jun 16 17:46 .escheck.tmp
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 164140486 Aug 26 19:47 VID_20180826_194513130.mp4
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 1624705 Aug 28 19:11 IMG_20180828_191133828.jpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 1426824 Aug 28 19:14 IMG_20180828_191424499.jpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 1166878 Aug 28 19:17 IMG_20180828_191700733.jpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 1372256 Aug 28 19:52 IMG_20180828_195257123.jpg
 ...
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode off.
ftp> mget *.*
local: *.* remote: *.*
200 PORT command successful
550 Requested action not taken. /DCIM/Camera/*.* : file does not exist
```

Everywhere I looked, * was a valid wildcard for all filenames. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the wildcard for `mget` is just a single `*`

Comment: Doesn't work
ftp> ls
    200 PORT command successful
    150 Directory listing for /ACRCalls/
    -rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 195052 Sep 10 14:43  1d20180910144243p5145893825.m4a
    drwxrwxrwx 1 system system 8192 Sep 15 08:43 .bin
-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 421822 Sep 11 13:33   1d20180911133131p5143437439.m4a
    -rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 4687805 Sep 14 13:34 0d20180914131025p18193421585.m4a
     226 Directory send OK.
    ftp> mget * 
`mget *? 
200 PORT command successful
550 Requested action not taken. /ACRCalls/* : file does not exist`

Comment: Try `.*`  Everywhere I am looking is showing that `*.*` is not used.  I did see the `.*` or `*.ext` work. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaiq/rzaiqmget.htm

Comment: @Terrance
Still doesn't work
    `-rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 195052 Sep 10 14:43 1d20180910144243p5145893825.m4a
    -rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 421822 Sep 11 13:33 1d20180911133131p5143437439.m4a
    -rw-rw-rw- 1 system system 4687805 Sep 14 13:34 0d20180914131025p18193421585.m4a
    226 Directory send OK.
    ftp> mget *.mp4
    mget *.mp4? 
    200 PORT command successful
    550 Requested action not taken. /ACRCalls/*.mp4 : file does not exist

Comment: on my last comment, last line should read:
`550 Requested action not taken. /ACRCalls/*.mp4 : file does not exist`

Comment: I just tested it between two systems here.  The only thing I noticed different between yours and mine is the file ownership.  My files stated that they are owned by 1000 both for the UID and the GID.  I was logging into the system as the owner name.  I was able to download with mget without any problems.  Maybe that is the hold up because your commands are correct.

Comment: I don't think privileges have anything to do with the issue since I can use get (one file at a time) and it works. When using Filezilla, drag and drop of multiple files work also.

Comment: I am just saying what I have observed as it works fine for me.  Something it wrong either on your server or client end because with your commands it should be working.  I have no more ideas for you.